# I've got a jQuery issue on responsible web. .slideToggle() shouldn't work when width of html is under 1050px, but It doesn't apply

Tags: html, jquery, css, width, responsive

I'm making vertical navigation for tablet pc.
As the title, .slideToggle() shouldn't work when width of html is under 1050px, but as like I reduce the page, still .slideToggle() is working. How can I fix it?

**here is HTML**

```
 <div class="header_con">
                <span><a href="#"></a></span>
                <p><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></p>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="depth1">
                        <li><a href="#">코로나-19</a>
                            <ul class="depth2">
                                <li><a href="#">손세정제</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">소독제</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">컬렉션</a>
                            <ul class="depth2">
                                <li><a href="#"><small>new</small>클레멘타인 앤 바질</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><small>new</small>베티버 앤 바이올렛</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">아로마테라피 시너지</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">허벌리스트</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">풋 리바이버</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">인블룸</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">크리스탈크러쉬</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">배스타임</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">선물세트/ 기프트세트</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">오일</a>
                            <ul class="depth2">
                                <li><a href="#">페이셜오일</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">멀티오일</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        .
                        .
                        .
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

**here is jQuery**

```
var html = $("html");
    var wid = $("html").width();
    var pc_wid = 1050;
    if(wid>=pc_wid){
        $(".depth1 li").on("mouseenter",function(){
                $(this).children("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);
            }).on("mouseleave",function(){
                $(this).children("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);
            });
    }else {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, your jQuery code is, when the document loads, watching if the width is greater or equal the pc_wid and, if it is, setting the events. It means that if you start with a large window and the resize to a small, you will have the events triggered, and, if you start with a small window and resize to a large window, it wont work.

Try something like this

```
var pc_wid = 1050;
$(".depth1 li").on("mouseenter",function(){
        if($("html").width() >= pc_wid)
            $(this).children("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);
    }).on("mouseleave",function(){
        if($("html").width() >= pc_wid)
            $(this).children("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);
    });
```

Here, you always set the event, but you just execute if the width is greater than the pc_wid.